# Drag and Drop Tiles in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm creating a dashboard type app in SwiftUI. For this dashboard I'm incorporating tiles of different sizes and functionalities. Below I have linked what I want the app to look like.

I want to make grid in SwiftUI look like this (For Mac), and make the drag and drop system similar to the widgets found in iOS.

[image: Dashboard Concept]

Answer (score -1):

You can't make this kind of view with SwiftUI alone, you will have to use UICollectionView and look into UICollectionDragDelegate and UICollectionDropDelegate to make your drag & drop functionality.

Wrap those inside a UIViewRepresentable and then use that in your SwiftUI view.

Comment: Update this is still in beta but it is not possible to do this natively in SwiftUI using the .draggable and .dropDestination modifiers.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-support-drag-and-drop-in-swiftui